# Why you mustn't write scanf("%.2lf", &a) in C?

Tags: c, scanf

My friend have just started learning programming. He showed me his code and asked why it return some weird number. After taking a look at it, I saw that he was using **scanf("%.2lf", &a)** to take input, and by habit, I try to change it to normal. Then he asked me why it has some strange output. After googling around I still haven't find the answer.

Can anybody tell me why it doesn't work?

Thank you in advance and sorry for the long irrelevant story as well as my bad English.

Edit: added code below

```
    int main()
    {
        double a,b,c,delta;
        printf("Nhap vao 3 so thuc a,b,c: \n");
        scanf("%.2lf %.2lf %.2lf",&a,&b,&c);
        if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0) printf("Phuong trinh co vo so nghiem");
        else if(a == 0 && b == 0 && c != 0) printf("Phuong trinh vo nghiem");
        else if(a == 0 && b != 0) printf("Phuong trinh co 1 nghiem la: %.2lf",-c/b);
        else if(a != 0)
        {
            delta=b*b-4*a*c;
            if(delta<0) printf("Phuong trinh vo nghiem");
            else if(delta == 0) printf("Phuong trinh co nghiem kep: %.2lf",-b/(2*a));
            else if(delta > 0) printf("Phuong trinh co 2 nghiem la:%.2lf, %.2lf",-(b-sqrt(delta))/(4*a),-(b+sqrt(delta))/(4*a));
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: _What_ didn't work?

Comment: It isn't valid syntax for a `scanf` conversion specification. What's valid for `printf()` isn't necessarily valid for `scanf()`. There isn't much else to say.  Specifically, the dot is not valid.

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of a?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok thank you, but I think it should have compile error if the syntax is invalid?

Comment: @andymango just added the full code.

It is in my mother language, maybe I will translate the to English if needed.

Comment: It's valid C syntax.  It is simply not valid use of `scabf()`.  Compilers do a lot; some would diagnose that.  Others don't.  The onus is on you to know what you're doing. The compiler does assume that.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard specifies that `scanf` conversion specifiers begin with `%`, and the POSIX standard specifies they begin with either `%` or `%n$`.

Neither the C standard nor the POSIX standard allows for a `.` in the conversion specifier, so this character is invalid.

You may have a decimal integer in your conversion specifier before the type specifier, but it specifies the *maximum field width* of the type. This means that `scanf` will read at most 2 characters before stopping when passed `%2lf`.

Additionally, `lf` specifies that the value should be a `double`, so a should be of type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The posted code does not work because it causes undefined behavior. The `.` character is not a valid directive or modifier for `scanf()` format strings. According to §7.21.6.2 13 of the C Standard, ["If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined"](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p13).

Frighteningly, one consequence of undefined behavior may be that code *appears* to work, at least sometimes. But then code may fail spectacularly under different circumstances, or on different platforms. This highlights the importance of always reading the documentation for any functions being used, with special attention paid to what the Standard has to say.