# C program: 'invalid format string conversion' with sscanf

Tags: c

Why do I get `invalid format string conversion` error for the below code?

```
sscanf("0", "%.2lf", &rate_amount);//default to zero
```

Comment: Don't specify the number of decimal places: `sscanf("0", "%lf", &rate_amount);`

Comment: Unlike output functions such as `printf` there is no such thing as precision for input functions like `sscanf`. That is, `.2` is invalid here.

Comment: @kaylum - How do I get precision of 2 with the stored value? ex. 0.00
Is that possible??

Comment: Jaguar Nation, the precision of `rate_amount` is not determine by how many textual digits was read, but by the type: `double`.  `1.5, 1234, 0.0625` all have similar precisions: about 1 part in 2^53.

Answer (score 1):

Format specifiers for the `scanf` family of functions don't have a precision.  For reading a `double`, `%lf` is enough.

```
sscanf("0", "%lf", &rate_amount);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438685/why-you-mustnt-write-scanf-2lf-a-in-c
Same holds for sscanf